# Can't upload images to Cloudinary with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary

It works perfectly in production (works fine on the local machine)
I also manually added the Cloudinary Url in Heroku's config vars
I provide Cloudinary credentials in the **cloudinary.yml** file
Deployed successfully to Heroku, the functionality related to Cloudinary (upload images) doesn't work but it works locally.
I am using Rails
and when I try:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

No errors appear

Comment: What is the response you receive from Cloudinary when attempting to upload?

Comment: No response, No Errors, Just not uploading

Comment: Share your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

My stupid mistake haha
Inside config/environments/production.rb

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

should be

```
 config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```